# Density function as derivative (Self-study)

Tags: calculus, probability

I'm trying to do the Society of Actuaries' example problems.  I am having trouble with no. 62, which says:

> A random variable $X$ has CDF
>   $$ F(x) = 
> \begin{cases} 0 & \text{for $x < 1$} \\
>               \frac{x^2 - 2x + 2}{2} & \text{for $1 \leq x < 2$} \\
>               1 & \text{for $x \geq 2$}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Compute the variance of $X$.

I understand the basic steps for computing the variance:

- Transform the CDF into a density $f$, by differentiating.
- Compute the expectation $E(X)$ by integrating $x f(x)$
- Compute the expectation $E(X^2)$ by integrating $x^2 f(x)$
- Compute the variance $V(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$.

The problem I'm having is that the density I compute does not match up with the one in the solutions page.  In particular, I get

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x - 1 & \text{for $1 \leq x < 2$}\\
                       0     & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

whereas they get

$$ 
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} & \text{for $x = 1$} \\
              x - 1       & \text{for $1 \leq x < 2$}\\
              0           & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Where is that $\frac{1}{2}$ coming from?

Edit:  I corrected the CDF, and now the derivative (if not the density) is correct.

Comment: Please, double check your CDF - it is not increasing (and is more than 1 for a good clip).

Comment: How did you get $x-1$? It should be $x+1$

Comment: @Alex: The CDF had a sign error during transcription to m.se

Comment: Your mistake is that you're neglecting the point mass as $x=1$.  The function jumps upward at that point, from $0$ to $1/2$.  That means the probability that $X=1$ is $1/2$.  This is not a continuous distribution nor a discrete distribution.  It has a discrete part, and the point mass at $1$ is it.  So the integrals your using won't do the whole problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that as $x$ approaches $1$ from the left, the cdf stays at $0$. Now calculate the cdf at $x=1$. Substituting $x=1$ into the formula, we have $F(1)=\frac{1}{2}$. So no "weight" up to but not including $1$, and then a sudden weight of $\frac{1}{2}$ **at** $1$.

Our overall distribution is neither discrete nor continuous. it has some features from each. That sort of distribution is often called a *mixed* distribution.

Before we do the remaining detailed calculations, we need to worry about the expression $\frac{x^2+2x-2}{2}$. Note that for $x$ near $2$ but to the left of $2$, this gives a number much bigger than $1$. That is absolutely impossible for a cdf.

**Added:** Now the cdf for $1\le x\lt 2$ has been fixed to $\frac{x^2-2x-2}{2}$, it is indeed a cdf.

To compute the variance, we probably first want to compute the mean. Differentiating, we find that the density function for $1\lt x\lt 2$ is $x-1$.

So we have a point mass of $\frac{1}{2}$ at $x=1$, and a wire of varying density stretching from $1$ to $2$. For the mean, we need to treat the two contributions to the mean separately, and add. We get
$$E(X)=(1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) +\int_{x=1}^2 x(x-1)\,dx.$$
This I think simplifies to $\frac{4}{3}$.

To complete the calculation of variance, we need $E(X^2)$. This is
$$(1^2)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) +\int_{x=1}^2 x^2(x-1)\,dx.$$